# Accessing RNN weights- Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using tf.python.ops.rnn_cell.GRUCell

```
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        GRUCell(HID_DIM),
        sequence,
        dtype=tf.float32,
        sequence_length=length(sequence)
)
```

How do I get the weights of this GRUCell. I need to see them for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of all the variables in the current session can be printed using:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    variables_names =[v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
    values = sess.run(variables_names)
    for k,v in zip(variables_names, values):
        print(k, v)
```